# add query to echo string

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code below:

```
<?php
//display random sorted list of terms in a given taxonomy
$counter = 0;
$max = 5; //number of categories to display
$taxonomy = 'category';
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
shuffle ($terms);
//echo 'shuffled';
if ($terms) {
foreach($terms as $term) {
$counter++;
if ($counter <= $max) {
echo '<p><a href="' . get_category_link( $term->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $term->name.'</a></p> ';
  }
 }
}
?>
```

inside echo I want to add this code so we can pull the latest post from the category.

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

I know this is basic PHP but how would we add this?

Comment: I'm a bit lost, but whats wrong with `<? while (have_posts()) { echo the_post(); } ?>`? And what is this the_post() function?

Comment: @CP510: Used to iterate through the post index.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post

Comment: You need to setup a new WP_Query or otherwise query for posts. The `while...` loop you have in your question would need to be after the actual query. You can't loop through posts that haven't been built from a database query. See here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query scroll all the way down to "Category Parameters"

Comment: Ahh I missed the wp tag. Nevermind, I don't use it so I wouldn't know.

Comment: The random category title pulls up perfectly I just want its latest post title and thumbnail to appear as well. I can handle the CSS